# MySQL. Horizontal display of attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to display horizontally the attribute.

For example, I have such tables:

[image]

And simple

```
SELECT user.name, project.name
FROM user
  LEFT JOIN project ON user.project_id = project.id;
```

gives me

```
User #1,Project #1
User #2,Project #1
User #3,Project #2
```

Is it possible to receive such a result? In one column project name and all related users to it.

```
Project #1
User #1
User #2
Project #2
User #3
```

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer.

Comment: @jarlh I understand, but that's close to impossible. I'm working with the legacy code. Is such workaround possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can generate your desired output using a `UNION` query along with a couple of inline columns to order the output.

```
SELECT t.name
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT project.name AS name,
                    project.id AS id,
                    0 AS idx
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN project
        ON user.project_id = project.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user.name,
           project.id,
           1
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN project
        ON user.project_id = project.id
) t
ORDER BY t.id,
         t.idx,
         t.name
```

Comment: It gives me 2 times "Project #1".

Comment: @D.R. I used `SELECT DISTINCT` for the first half of the `UNION` subquery and it appears to be working now.